# Highstocks rounding values, and range not accurate for more then two hours of viewing

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts to perform sensor graphing for basic temperatures, or things of that nature. The issue is I have the current default view set at 3 days, but at that view it distorts the y axis data values.

For example, if the majority of the data is 1.5 but there is a value of 10 also, in the three day view the y axis is only showing a range up to 3 or 4. It shows the spike in the actual line graph however when you hover over the point the value is 3 or 4 instead of 10. However, if I shrink the view to 2 hours, the data gets displayed properly and the value then returns to 10 and the y axis accomodates the 10 value.

Also I am having issues with the data being rounded down constantly it seems, since the values should be a steady 1.5 it is constantly being rounded down to 1.

Any help will be appreciated and I will be around the computer all day to answer any questions that someone might have about this issue.

```
$.getJSON('mkjson.php?device=<?echo $device_name;?>&sensor=<?echo $sensor_name;?>&pin=<?echo $pin;?>&user=<?echo $_SESSION['user'];?>', function(data) {
    // Create the chart
    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart : {
            renderTo : 'container',
            zoomType: 'x'
        },

        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        title : {

            text : 'Device:<?echo $device_name;?>'
        },
        subtitle : {
            text : 'Sensor:<?echo $sensor_name;?>'

        },

        xAxis : {
            minRange: 600 * 1000 // one hour
        },

        yAxis : {
            title : {
                text : '<?echo $unit;?>'
            }


        },
        rangeSelector : {
            buttons : [{
                type : 'minute',
                count : 10,
                text : '10m'
            }, {
                type : 'hour',
                count : 1,
                text : '1H'
            }, {
                type : 'day',
                count : 1,
                text : '1D'
            },
            {
                type : 'day',
                count : 3,
                text : '3D'
            }],
            selected : 3,
            inputEnabled : false
        },          

        series : [{
            name : 'Voltage',
            data : data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

This is the example of how the data is skewed. The high points to the right are 10, and 13 yet they show up at only 3.
[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`dataGrouping`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.line.dataGrouping) as it lets you determine how to group or to have it off completely. It defaults to enabled.

Comment: That fixed the issue for the y axis range thanks!

However the values are still being autorounded down from 1.5 to 1, do you know what that issue might be?

Comment: Without seeing a sampling of your data (maybe in a jsFiddle) it is hard to say. Perhaps move the `tooltip` settings out of the series object and place within the chart section?

Comment: The tool tip is still showing two decimal places that I asked it to, however where the number should be 1.5 it is showing up on the graph as only one.

Comment: I would have to see a sample set of code that reproduces this issue in order to answer that question.

Comment: Paste data will be helfpul, as wergeld posted.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use numberFormat() http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#highcharts.numberFormat()

Answer (score 0):

I've been burned by the auto-rounding; the chart does some sort of value rounding for its internal representation of points.

I only have a workaround - I got around it by storing the data points in a separate array and referencing THAT in the tooltip function.

As of note, if you're using column data and don't turn data grouping off, the chart will round your X values too.